# Architecture for driving complex Use Cases

Tags: architecture, use-case, presentation-model, dci

I'm about to design a software to be implemented by several developers.

The software has many complex use cases involving several steps and commands from the UI.
I want to have a clear separation from the UI and the Bussiness logic, so, the different
states of each use case should not be driven/controlled by the UI but in a lower layer, 
making the UI essentially 'dumb'.

I've considered a mixture between DCI and State patterns to solve this.

I would like to know your experience with similar applications and, if possible,
receive your advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Focus on the use cases, and don't worry about buzzwords like "DCI", "State Patterns" or any other other cool terminology.  Remember: the *Fundamental design pattern* is "K.I.S.S".  IMHO... ;)

Comment: @Paulsm4 one of the goals of DCI is to make use case implementations simple so your comment is self contradicting

Comment: I would suggest you to read Lean Development Book by Jim Coplien who is a pioneer for DCI. IMHO this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as the concept is, introducing DCI (or any other new concept for that matter) to a big group of developers can be costly. If it's a long term project it might make sense.

On the other hand, if what you want to achieve is

> a clear separation from the UI and the Bussiness logic

then Model-View-Controller (MVC) is a more established pattern, as well as Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) for JavaScript and Windows Presentation Foundation applications.